# Using ng-bootstrap with angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.18

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng-bootstrap

I'm using angular-cli 1.0.0-beta. 18 and trying to load ng-bootstrap using the guidline at https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started

**Steps:**

Install ng-bootstrap using

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

Added the following to app.module.ts

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ...],
  imports: [NgbModule.forRoot(), ...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

For my ibox-tools.module.ts I have

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {IboxToolsComponent} from "./ibox-tools.component.ts";
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [IboxToolsComponent],
    imports     : [NgbModule, BrowserModule],
    exports     : [IboxToolsComponent],
})

export class IboxToolsModule {}
```

And then I try to use ngbDropdown module in my ibox-tools.template.html

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
        <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownMenu1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                <button class="dropdown-item">Action - 1</button>
                <button class="dropdown-item">Another Action</button>
                <button class="dropdown-item">Something else is here</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But ngbDropdown doesnt work. I dont get any errors, bootstrap4.css is included etc.

The getting started guide tells me to use

```
map: {
  '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': 'node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js',
}
```

If im using SystemJS, but I dont think thats the case, as angular-cli 1.0.0-beta. 18 is using Webpack and should load ng-bootstrap automatically. Am I wrong here? I dont find any place where I should add the mapping, anyone else managed to use ng-bootstrap with angular-cli 1.0.0-beta. 18?

Comment: What's happening? You haven't actually described a problem, except that it "doesn't work". What exactly does that mean? How are you adding the css?

Comment: AFAIK, _Bootstrap Dropdown_ uses JS hooks. Thus without that required JS included it results in a non-functional/static Dropdown without any error message in console.

Comment: @peeskillet The problem is more like 'how to add third party libraries using angular-cli 1.0.0-beta. 18 with webpack?'. Before you could add mapping in systemjs config file to import the @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap, but now I thought it should be loaded automatically when using webpack. Does I still have to add mapping any other place? The css is loaded normaly with   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link> in index.html but it doesnt look like the ng-bootstrap library actually is loaded..

Comment: did you tried to add `NgbModule.forRoot()` in IboxToolsModule?

Comment: I have the same problem, I have upgraded from beta.14 which works fine, to beta.18 and NgbDropdown just does not work when you click on it, not dropdown effect. I have been using NgbDropdownModule.forRoot() but also tried NgbModule.forRoot()

Comment: I would try to use angular material2s select instead if it is a selection box. Works alot smoother @DavidCruwys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my bad. Im still learning angular2 and the problem was that I included my ibox-tools.**component**.ts into another module, and not the ibox-tools.**module**.ts which was needed, so I missed ng-bootstrap for the secondary module which was imported in ibox-tools.module.ts ;)

So webpack is working great and no need for mapping as you had to with systemjs.

Hope you understand my answer, if not just ask and I can try to explain better.